# entity-framework 5 initialize not null properties on createObject

Tags: entity-framework-5

I'm getting a problem when creating an instance of an entity in entity framework 5.
 I'm creating it by reflection:

```
var method = this.objectContextinstance().GetType().GetMethod("CreateObject");
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType("PERSON"));
var entity = method.Invoke(this.objectContextinstance(), null);
```

the problem is that the not null properties are being initialized with zero, and i don't want it to.
The reason is that if i save it, it makes a reference to another object that key is zero creating wrong data.

is there a way of creating an instance and it not automatically set the non null properties or is there a configuration to set the not null properties to a value like '-1'?

The problem i mention happens creating a instance of some entity by the "new" clause.

I'm using DataBase First approach.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I set all of the properties to a default value after creation:

```
    public void InitializeCreatedEntity(object entity)
    {
        Type tipoObj = entity.GetType();

        string nomeEntidade = GetNomeEntidade(entity);

        foreach (EntityType entityType in EntityTypes)
        {
            if (entityType.Name.Equals(nomeEntidade))
            {
                foreach (EdmProperty property in entityType.Properties)
                {
                    if (!property.Nullable)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo info = tipoObj.GetProperty(property.Name);

                        switch (property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name)
                        {
                            case "String": info.SetValue(entity, "", null);
                                break;
                            case "Int32": info.SetValue(entity, DefaultInt, null);
                                break;
                            case "Int64": info.SetValue(entity, DefaultInt, null);
                                break;
                            case "Int16": info.SetValue(entity, DefaultInt, null);
                                break;
                            case "Binary": Byte[] initByteArray = { };
                                info.SetValue(entity, initByteArray, null);
                                break;
                            case "DateTime": info.SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now, null);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```